# Make R consider negative position searches as being out of bounds

Tags: r, subscript

`vec<-c("a", "b", "c", "d")`
my task is to extract the second element from the right and left of the key string.

If our key string is "d", if we do

```
i<-c("d")
vec.1 <- append(vec.1, vec[which(vec == i) + 2])
```

we get NA. But if we do

```
i<-c("a")    
vec.1 <- append(vec.1, vec[which(vec == i) - 2])
```

we get "b", "c", "d". Is it possible to consider negative values in subscripts as positions being out of the vector like a positive subscript that exceeds the length of the vector? That way the result will be a NA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(Hmisc)

Lag(vec,2)[vec=="d"]
#[1] "b"

Lag(vec,2)[vec=="a"]
#[1] ""

Lag(vec,-2)[vec=="a"]
#[1] "c"

Lag(vec,-2)[vec=="c"]
#[1] ""
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure I could do better, but it's late here. Why not write a small function to do what you want.

```
myVec <- function(input, match, change) {
  temp = which(input == match)
  if ((temp + change) <= 0) {
    append(NA, input)
  } else {
    append(input, input[temp + change])
  }
}

vec <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

myVec(vec, "a", -1)
# [1] NA  "a" "b" "c" "d"
myVec(vec, "c", -1)
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "b"
myVec(vec, "c", -3)
# [1] NA  "a" "b" "c" "d"
myVec(vec, "d", 1)
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" NA
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I just want the element of the indicated position in the result. Instead of
# [1] NA  "a" "b" "c" "d", I need just [1] NA.

Comment: @jackson, no problem. I assumed this is what you wanted because you were using `append()`.